# acess to userName from jsp using spring security

Tags: exception, spring-security

I want to output userName if he log in.
From @Controller i have access:

```
@RequestMapping("/success")
    public String success(Model model) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String name = auth.getName(); //get logged in username
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "success";
    }
```

It work an if i use name on jsp, I see typed name.

But if in this jsp I write

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
    <sec:authentication property="principal.username"/>
```

I get stackTrace:

```
 INFO : com.epam.hhsystem.util.CustomAuthentificationProvider - User with name 'Nikolay_Tkachev' log in
07.08.2013 17:00:57 org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache tldScanJar
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
07.08.2013 17:00:57 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'principal.username' of bean class [org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken]: Bean property 'principal.username' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:699)
```

...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you have authentiucation using using username and password, principal is it self the name of user. try using

```
<sec:authentication property="principal"/>
```

Comment: Why everywhere write  <sec:authentication property="principal.username"/> ?

Comment: AFAIK, if you have a simple username and password, username can be stored directly in principal as a string. But if you have extra details like company name, department etc with username , you can assign a customized object to principal and hence in that case you will use principal,username